# Pythons Multiprocessing pool not running in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am currently trying to calculate the closest neighbors for thousands of vectors to millions of vectors with 50 dimensions in python. Letting it run sequentially seems like a huge waste of time, so I wanted to parallelize it.

First I load the preprocessed data with pickle, where I have a dict with my objects p as they keys and their vector form (p2v) as their value, and some ids that determine which ps will be looked at. I then partition the ids into 8 chunks, so that each process has to calclulate the neighbors for multiple p. The method find_closest_n_chunks takes an array of ids and looks in the p2v dict for the vector. Then it goes through the whole dict to calculate the nearest neighbor (for my test I look at only 10 elements from the dict).

Currently I work on a windows machine with the following code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import pickle

def find_closest_n_chunks(ids, p2v, n):
    print("starting a chunk")
    neighbors = []
    for p in ids:
        p2distance = {}
        vector = p2v[p]
        for key in list(p2v.keys())[:10]:
            distance = cosine(vector, p2v[key])
            p2distance[key] = distance
        sorted_by_distance = sorted(p2distance.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
        neighbors.append(sorted_by_distance[:n])
    print("finished chunk")
    return neighbors

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = open('./prelim_results/DataHandlerC08.obj', "rb")
    handler = pickle.load(file)
    file = open("./prelim_results/vectorsC08.obj", "rb")
    p2v = pickle.load(file)
    ids = handler.evaluation_ids

    chunks = []
    chunk_p2v = []
    for _ in range(8):
        chunks.append([])
        chunk_p2v.append(p2v.copy())
    for idx, p in enumerate(ids):
        array_idx = idx % 8
        chunks[array_idx].append(p)
    print("starting")
    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(processes=8, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        results = []
        for idx, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            results.append(pool.apply_async(find_closest_n_chunks, (chunk, chunk_p2v[idx], 100)))
        for result in results:
            step = time.time()
            print("step: {0}".format(step-start))
            result.wait()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

This works fine in starting multiple different processes, however, they do not work in parallel on my 4 core (8 with multithreading) CPU. The output confirms this:

```
starting
step: 0.1266627311706543
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 15.884509086608887
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 24.54252290725708
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 33.269429445266724
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 42.065810680389404
```

The message "starting a chunk" is only called after "finished a chunk", and each chunk takes around 8-9 seconds, meaning that each chunk will only started after the other is finished.

Notice, I already tried to copy the p2v object, to make sure I have no shared object between the tasks (as expected, since its read only, this changed nothing).

Can you point out any mistake I did in trying to parallelize it?

Edit: Added imports at top of code and the pickle statements that load my vectors and ids

Edit2: I swapped out find_closest_n_chunk() with a dummy method:

```
def dummy():
    print("start dummy")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("end dummy")
```

This gave me the correct output, where all process would be started before the first was finished. I then added a time.sleep(20) to the actual find_closest method directly after the starting print line. This showed that there is some parallelization:

```
starting
step: 0.07980728149414062
starting a chunk
starting a chunk
starting a chunk
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 35.71958327293396
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 45.673808574676514
finished chunk
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 55.73376154899597
step: 55.73949694633484
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 64.74968791007996
starting a chunk
finished chunk
step: 73.77850985527039
finished chunk
step: 82.86862134933472
finished chunk
91.36373448371887
```

But it takes like 5-10 seconds for each of the "starting a chunk" to appear. So they do not start at the same time

Comment: Can you show your import statements as well?   I ran a reduced version of your code and it does run in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I added the imports and the pickle statements that load my vectors and ids

Comment: By now I have tried the code on multiple different computers (one Linux) and it is not working either

Comment: This is bizarre as your code seems to work on my computer - but of course I do not have your data structures.  This is a bit far fetched but could you create a test program without any of your data structures. Just a worker that does sleep(3) and returns an integer, and your with mp.Pool() structure identical without your data structures either.  This would allow us to see if there is something that blocks parallel execution in general or is this related to your data / volume of your data

Comment: And does anything change if you took your for result in results: loop outside the with structure - meaning the pool would be closed before you started accessing results?  These are just shots in the dark as your code looks fine.

Comment: Edited in your first comment. If I put the result loop outside of the structure the program starts, but does not terminate. This was really strange

Comment: Ok I have done some further tests. If I increase the for key in list(p2v.keys())[:10]: to 10000, then the parallelization works fine. Multiple chunks will be started before one is finished. However, it still needs around 10 seconds for the "starting a chunk" to appear. I assume, that this is because the p2v dict may be to big. It contains 1.2 millions 50 dimension vectors. Probably it just takes 10 seconds for a process to be created before it can start. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you try "fixing" it by loading the static data into global variables and not passing it as parameters to your pool workers?  If you need to pass split keys, that would be ok ("this worker processes items from a to b")?      Leave the result loop then where it was, it was clearly not causing any issues there.

Comment: I put now  file = open("./prelim_results/vectorsC08.obj", "rb")
p2v = pickle.load(file) directly after the imports and before the method. It did not help. However, I am satasfied with the current result. I thank you for your help!